# Find maximum sum of n/2 elements of an integer array with n(n is even) elements by picking either leftmost element of rightmost at once

Tags: arrays, max

Suppose I have an integer array `arr[]` with `n` elements. I've to display the maximum possible sum of `n/2` elements. I'm allowed to pick either the leftmost or the rightmost element while traversing to find the sum.
For instance,

```
arr = 2,100,4,5,6,7,140,1 where n = 8.
```

So I've to find 4 elements such that their sum is the maximum possible sum and display the sum then.

```
Possible sets are = {(2,100,4,5),(2,100,4,1),(2,100,140,1),(2,7,140,1),(6,7,140,1)}.
(2,100,140,1) has maximum sum of 243 and hence the expected output.
```

Another example could be,

```
arr = 4,5,6,7,8,9 with n = 6.
Thus, n/2 = 3. Expected out 24 (7,8,9).
```

Can someone help with the logic?

Comment: Have you tired something ? where is your code ?

Comment: You can just sum all the possible options and select the one with the highest. It is still linear complexity. There is no special logic needed.